# Can a Loxodon PC wield a 2-handed sword and a shield with one hand and their trunk?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits

Could a Loxodon in full plate armor with tower shield in one hand, wield a greatsword with the other hand and their trunk?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, what exactly do you mean by this? What makes you think that the rules might work in this way?

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. This is a good first question but it might help answerers if you identify which version of the Loxodon race you are using, I assume the version from Unearthed Arcana but it helps to be specific. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Where are you getting a tower shield in 5e?

Answer (score 30):

### Nope, not by RAW.

From Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica (p18), in the Loxodon's traits:

> ***Trunk.*** ... Your trunk can't wield weapons or shields or do anything that requires manual precision.

Unless of course you have a generous DM who is willing to bend the rules, then that's their call.

Comment: Indeed! ...and yet ironic, since elephants in the real world take years to master using their trunks because of the sheer scale of muscle memory it requires to master them. I reckon Loxodon should be allowed to at least play darts with their trunks. :)